# How to check if the clicked element is equal to an object from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if the clicked element is equal to an object from an array?
Here is my code:

```js
// Question app where you must choose between two different answers. The problem is next: I don't know how to check if the clicked div is equal to the object from the array.
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $answer_1 = $(".a_1_h2"); //store the <h2> for the answer 1
  var $answer_2 = $(".a_2_h2"); //store the <h2> for the answer 2
  var $question = $(".question_h2"); //store the <h2> for the question
  var $counter = 0;
  var $score = $("<h2 class='score'></h2>");
  var content_list = [{
    "answer_1_val": "Yes",
    "answer_2_val": "No",
    "question_val": "Question_1?",
    "correct_val": "Yes"
  }, {
    "answer_1_val": "No",
    "answer_2_val": "Yes",
    "question_val": "Question_2?",
    "correct_val": "No"
  }]; //answers(2), question 

  $(".main_div").append($score);
  $score.text($counter);
  $(".a_1").append($answer_1); // append variable to div
  $(".a_2").append($answer_2); // append variable to div

  $(".start_button").click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'index.html'; //redirect to another page
  });

  $answer_1.html(content_list[0].answer_1_val); //attach answer_1_val to the <h2> variable
  $answer_2.html(content_list[0].answer_2_val); //attach answer_2_val to the <h2> variable
  $question.html(content_list[0].question_val); //attach question_val to the <h2> variable

  if ($(".a_1").click().is($answer_1)) {
    $score.text($counter += 10);
  } else {
    $score.text($counter -= 10);
  } // check if the clicked element is equal with the value from the object
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<section>
  <div class="main_div">
    <div class="overall_div">
      <div class="answers_div">
        <div class="a_1">
          <h2 class="a_1_h2"></h2>
          <!--placeholder for answer_1-->
        </div>
        <div class="vs">
          <h2>VS</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="a_2">
          <h2 class="a_2_h2"></h2>
          <!--placeholder for answer_2-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="questions_div">
        <h2 class="question_h2"></h2>
        <!--placeholder for question-->
      </div
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Give them an id or other identifier and compare those? Or use the event target, (in most jquery event handlers it should be accesible with 'this' as well) and copare the target with the element in the array.

Comment: Looked at your code 5 times and still confused.. you are just storing some element in a variable then assigning it to its own parent and then trying to change it with some text as html.. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```js
// Question app where you must choose between two different answers. The problem is next: I don't know how to check if the clicked div is equal to the object from the array.
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $answer_1 = $(".a_1_h2"); //store the <h2> for the answer 1
  var $answer_2 = $(".a_2_h2"); //store the <h2> for the answer 2
  var $question = $(".question_h2"); //store the <h2> for the question
  var $counter = 0;
  var $score = $("<h2 class='score'></h2>");
  var content_list = [{
    "answer_1_val": "Yes",
    "answer_2_val": "No",
    "question_val": "Question_1?",
    "correct_val": "Yes"
  }, {
    "answer_1_val": "No",
    "answer_2_val": "Yes",
    "question_val": "Question_2?",
    "correct_val": "No"
  }]; //answers(2), question 

  $(".main_div").append($score);
  $score.text($counter);
  $(".a_1").append($answer_1); // append variable to div
  $(".a_2").append($answer_2); // append variable to div
  
  $(".start_button").click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'index.html'; //redirect to another page
  });

  $answer_1.html(content_list[0].answer_1_val); //attach answer_1_val to the <h2> variable
  $answer_2.html(content_list[0].answer_2_val); //attach answer_2_val to the <h2> variable
  $question.html(content_list[0].question_val); //attach question_val to the <h2> variable
  $("#a1").val(content_list[0].answer_1_val); // assign value to radio button
  $("#a2").val(content_list[0].answer_2_val);// assign value to radio button
  
  $("input[name='ans']").change(function(){ // check on click which button has been clicked
    if($("input[name='ans']:checked").val() == content_list[0].correct_val){ //compare clicked value with correct value
      $score.text($counter += 10);
    } else {
      $score.text($counter -= 10);
    }
  })  // check if the clicked element is equal with the value from the object
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<section>
  <div class="main_div">
    <div class="overall_div">
      <div class="answers_div">
        <div class="a_1">
          <input type="radio" id="a1" name="ans"><label class="a_1_h2"></label>
          <!--I dont know where you are clicking so i have created radio button-->
        </div>
        <div class="vs">
          <h2>VS</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="a_2">
          <input type="radio" id="a1" name="ans"><label class="a_2_h2"></label>
          <!--I dont know where you are clicking so i have created radio button-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="questions_div">
        <h2 class="question_h2"></h2>
        <!--placeholder for question-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing elements on different hierarchical positions. Change

```
if ($(".a_1").click().is($answer_1)) {
```

to

```
if ($(".a_1_h2").click().is($answer_1)) {
```

and you will get the right result.

But, besides that, I don't think comparing elements is a good implementation for this. It would be better to compare the answer value directly.